# Magento update with csv and unset special price

Tags: magento, csv, import

I'm trying to update a product in Magento through Import/Export -> Import, using a .csv file. I'm passing just `_sku`, `_type`, `_attribute_set`, `_store`, `price` and `special_price` columns. I want to unset the current special price of the product, but when I pass an empty string it sets the special price to 0. I tried with `null`, `"NULL"` and `"<NULL>"` but the result is the same. When the value is 0 it is still shown as special price on the front end, which is really confusing. That's why I want to set it to `null`, as this is the value it receives when it's being removed from the admin.

My goal is the equivalent of this:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(some_id);
$product->setSpecialPrice('');
$product->save();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just realized that setting the special price a value that is equal to the value of the regular price will do the job. Then the template for the special price will not be used on the front end. I hope it will not bring some other issues, but for now it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You cant remove it with a regular csv import.  Your best bet would be to add coloumn;

```
special_to_date
```

and set a date in the past in this format;

```
31/10/2014 00:00
```

This will expire your special price.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. About the `$product->setSpecialPrice('');` - it works, I just tried it ;)

Comment: no problem, and thanks for headsup ill edit the answer.